# DataGrid.SetBinding ItemsSource - Зависание UI

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, binding, datagrid

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { 
    dataGrid.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding() { Source = dataTable 
});
```

Сначала я заполняю DataTable нужными мне значениями, а затем делаю привязку DataGrid к этой таблице. Однако, я встретился с такой проблемой как зависание интерфейса в момент вызова `SetBinding`.

DataTable заполняется в отдельном потоке, из которого вызывается `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. `IsAsync=True` в Binding и различные приоритеты `BeginInvoke` не помогают. Что можно сделать?

Comment: Профайлером глядели? Что именно тормозит UI?

Comment: Dispatcher Invoke

Comment: это само по себе ничего не тормозит. Я спрашиваю какой конкретно код подвисает ваш UI поток?

Comment: Dispatcher Invoke в смысле наиболее загружен. Я описании вопроса я указал, что вызов SetBinding "подвешивает" UI. Как конкретно выглядит вызов вы тоже можете посмотреть там же...

Comment: Пример бы для воспроизведения

Comment: ну вы показали просто биндинг. Вероятно он начинает перечислять строки таблицы. Попробуйте таблицу создать и заполнить руками в памяти и также забиндить - будет ли он также тормозить или нет. Да и что значит тормозит? Просто подлагивает или полчаса висит?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Проект с упрощённым кодом кинуть? Просто кладёте на окно DataGrid, ставите `AutoGenerateColumns=True`, создаёте DataTable в отдельном потоке и через Dispatcher биндите ItemsSource к созданной таблице. Если это как то пояснит ситуацию...

Comment: @tym32167 "Попробуйте таблицу создать и заполнить руками в памяти и также забиндить" - Таблицу? Это вы про DataTable? "Да и что значит тормозит?" - Полностью зависает и через несколько секунд развисает с уже заполненным значениями DataGrid.

Comment: `Это вы про DataTable?` да

Comment: Дак так и делаю. Заполняю руками в памяти, а потом делаю привязку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смог повторить ваш эксперимент - действительно медленно отрабатывает. Но медленно отрабатывает не привязка, а код, который выполняет датагрид ПОСЛЕ привязки.

Например:

```
public class MyWnd : Window
{
    DataGrid dg;

    public MyWnd()
    {
        dg = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid() {AutoGenerateColumns = true};
        var bt = new Button() { Content = "Load" };
        bt.Click += Load;

        var sp = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical};
        sp.Children.Add(bt);
        sp.Children.Add(dg);

        this.Content = sp;
    }

    public async void Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = null;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            dt = new DataTable();

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add($"Column{i}");
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                var row = dt.NewRow();

                for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    var col = $"Column{j}";
                    row[col] = i + j;
                }

                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        });

        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();     

        dg.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding()
        {
            Source = dt, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
        });     

        sw.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show($"Elapsed: {sw.Elapsed}");
    }
}
```

Этот код при нажатии кнопки Load сначала создаст таблицу, забиндит её, остановит часы и уже после этого (но перед отображением мессаджбокса) зависнет. Потому у меня часики всегда показывают очень маленький интервал времени

[image: Часы]

Я думаю, это связано с самим контролом DataGrid. Он либо не умеет в виртуализацию и потому пытается рендерить все строки сразу (при 10 строчках работает оч быстро), либо и без этого у него проблемы с производительностью, например [раз](http://www.mindscapehq.com/forums/thread/457035), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680879/wpf-datagrid-is-very-slow-to-render?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Хотя скорее всего и то и то.

**UPD**

Чтобы побороть это надо правильно включить виртуализацию и положить грид в контрол, который ограничит его размеры. Выглядит это так:

```
public class MyWnd : Window
{
    DataGrid dg;

    public MyWnd()
    {
        dg = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid()
        {
            AutoGenerateColumns = true,
            EnableRowVirtualization = true,
            EnableColumnVirtualization = true
        };
        VirtualizingPanel.SetIsVirtualizing(dg, true);
        ScrollViewer.SetCanContentScroll(dg, true);
        Grid.SetRow(dg, 1);

        var bt = new Button() { Content = "Load" };
        bt.Click += Load;

        var grid = new Grid();

        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { });

        grid.Children.Add(bt);
        grid.Children.Add(dg);

        this.Content = grid;    
    }

    public async void Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = null;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            dt = new DataTable();

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add($"Column{i}");
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                var row = dt.NewRow();

                for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    var col = $"Column{j}";
                    row[col] = i + j;
                }

                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        });

        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        dg.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding()
        {
            Source = dt
        });

        sw.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show($"Elapsed: {sw.Elapsed}");
    }
}
```

Так как размеры контрола ограниченны и включена виртуализация, то грид не будет пытаться все сразу отрисовать, а будет отрисовывать только видимую часть

[image: результат]

**УПД 2**

Добавление строки

```
public class MyWnd : Window
{
    DataGrid dg;

    public MyWnd()
    {
        dg = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid()
        {
            AutoGenerateColumns = true,
            EnableRowVirtualization = true,
            EnableColumnVirtualization = true
        };
        VirtualizingPanel.SetIsVirtualizing(dg, true);
        ScrollViewer.SetCanContentScroll(dg, true);
        Grid.SetRow(dg, 1);

        var bt = new Button() { Content = "Load" };
        bt.Click += Load;

        var btrow = new Button() { Content = "AddRow" };
        btrow.Click += AddRow;

        var sp = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
        sp.Children.Add(bt);
        sp.Children.Add(btrow);

        var grid = new Grid();

        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { });

        grid.Children.Add(sp);
        grid.Children.Add(dg);

        this.Content = grid;
    }

    DataTable dt = null;
    Random r = new Random();

    public async void AddRow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newRow = dt.NewRow();       
        for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            var col = $"Column{j}";
            newRow[col] = r.Next(10);
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
    public async void Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            dt = new DataTable();

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add($"Column{i}");
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var row = dt.NewRow();

                for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    var col = $"Column{j}";
                    row[col] = i + j;
                }

                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        });

        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        dg.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding()
        {
            Source = dt
        });

        sw.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show($"Elapsed: {sw.Elapsed}");
    }
}
```

Результат

[image: Добавление строки]

Comment: У меня большое количество не строчек - столбцов (более 100). `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing` и `VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode` не помогают.

Comment: Вы объяснили причину, но не предложили конкретного решения.

Comment: Может быть, используя DataGrid, это просто не возможно?

Comment: У меня так же есть ещё один вопрос на счёт DataGrid. Он не по теме, но я не хотел бы создавать отдельную тему для этого.

Comment: @D.Stark Смотрите апдейт

Comment: На счёт ещё одного вопроса: как можно добавить строчку в готовый DataGrid? Т.е. есть у меня DataGrid, в нём все столбцы оформлены, нужно добавить в Items новое значение заключённое в строковом массиве. Binding в DataGridColumn так же нужно не использовать.

Comment: @D.Stark если в привязанный источник данных добавить нет возможности, то тогда задавайте это отдельным вопросом с конкретным примером кода. Я сам не спец по датагриду, просто капельку погуглил и дополнил ответ.

Comment: В источник данных добавить можно. Но при этом при привязке ведь собьются свойства столбцов DataGrid (ширина например).

Comment: @D .Stark, почему они должны сбиться?

Comment: Если создать DataTable, заполнить Columns как заполнено в DataGrid, добавлять значения, а потом привязать ItemsSource к DataTable, ширина столбцов указанная в разметке будет изменена.

Comment: @D.Stark добавил добавление строки

Comment: Не то. Попробуйте сделать без ItemsSource Binding

Comment: Я хочу чтобы ширина столбцов после привязки к DataTable не менялась

Comment: @D.Stark не, я гадать не буду, как именно вам надо добавлять строки. Задавайте это отдельным вопросом.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо

Comment: У вашего решения есть побочный эффект: при перечислении всех значений ячеек таблицы методом `GetCellContent` результат окажется неверным - только видимая часть таблицы будет обработана...

Comment: Вопросов почему как бы нет.. Как исправить, если знаете?

Comment: @D.Stark в этом суть виртуализации. Если вам надо пройтись по данным, делайте это в источнике данных, а не в гриде